# ¿Cómo debo configurar correctamente Django Channels y Redis?

Tags: django, redis

Saludos a toda la comunidad. Estoy obteniendo un error alguna veces cuando ejecuto un Worker de Django Channels como Background Task (tarea en segundo plano). La tarea consume un WebSocket abierto de un tercero (third party) con una librería llamada Pysher, procesa esa data para luego enviar la data resultante a través del Channel Layer a un grupo de Websockets escuchando nuestra aplicación usando Redis, que es un manejador de mensajes.

Sé que el problema no tiene que ver con la librería Pysher, ya que si comento el código de enviar el mensaje a través del Channel Layer no arroja ningún problema. **El problema ocurre debido al envío del mensaje en el Channel Layer** y solo ocurre algunas veces, muchas veces el envío ocurre de forma exitosa y otras veces arroja el error, lo último me hace pensar que puede tener que ver con **Redis o el Channel Layer y su configuración o algo por el estilo.**

**Mensaje de Error obtenido**

error from callback bound method Connection._on_message of Connection(Thread-2, started daemon 140614612023040):
[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

**Sistema Operativo** Ubuntu 16 + Redis 3.2

**Pip Dependencies**

aiodns==1.1.1
aiohttp==2.3.10
aioredis==1.0.0
amqp==2.2.2
asgiref==2.1.6
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==1.6.1
async-timeout==2.0.0
attrs==17.4.0
autobahn==17.10.1
Automat==0.6.0
Babel==2.5.3
billiard==3.5.0.3
biopython==1.69
cchardet==2.1.1
celery==4.1.0
certifi==2018.1.18
cffi==1.11.4
channels==2.0.2
channels-redis==2.1.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.1.4
daphne==2.0.4
dash==0.21.0
dash-core-components==0.21.1
dash-html-components==0.9.0
dash-renderer==0.11.3
decorator==4.2.1
Django==2.0.2
django-celery-beat==1.1.1
django-celery-results==1.0.1
django-mysql==2.2.0
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Caching==1.4.0
Flask-Compress==1.4.0
flower==0.9.2
future==0.16.0
hiredis==0.2.0
hyperlink==17.3.1
idna==2.6
idna-ssl==1.0.0
incremental==17.5.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==4.3.4
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
kombu==4.1.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
mccabe==0.6.1
msgpack==0.5.6
multidict==4.1.0
mysqlclient==1.3.12
nbformat==4.4.0
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.4
numpy==1.13.3
oauthlib==2.0.7
pandas==0.22.0
plotly==2.5.1
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pycares==2.3.0
pycparser==2.18
pylint==1.8.2
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
Pysher==0.3.0
PySocks==1.6.8
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-telegram-bot==10.0.1
python-twitter==3.4.1
pytz==2018.3
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
service-identity==17.0.0
six==1.11.0
tornado==4.5.3
traitlets==4.3.2
Twisted==17.9.0
txaio==2.8.2
urllib3==1.22
vine==1.1.4
websocket-client==0.47.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wrapt==1.10.11
yarl==1.1.0
zope.interface==4.4.3

**Configuración del Channel Layer**

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)]
        },
    },
}
```

**My code**

```
# Clase de Synconsumer que corre como Worker en segundo plano
class BTWorker(SyncConsumer):

# Metodo de procesamiento de la data
def get_data(self, event):

    # Función Callback que se ejecuta cada que se recibe un mensaje del websocket
    def callback(*args, **kwargs):
        # Transformación de data previo al envío via Channel Layer
        raw_dict = json.loads(args[0])
        var_dict = {
            'id': raw_dict['id'],
            'other_key': other_value
        }
        var_list = [var_dict]

        # Envío de la información de la data via Channel Layer y Redis (codigo que GENERA EL ERROR!!)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "group_name",
            {
                "type": "some.type",
                "text": json.dumps(trade_uni_list)
            }
        )

    # Función para conexión con Websocket de tercero
    def connect_handler(data):
        channel = pusher.subscribe('token')
        channel.bind('channel', callback)

    # Logica para conectarse al websocket del Third Party via Pusher
    pusher = pysher.Pusher('******some_key****')
    pusher.connection.bind('pusher:connection_established', connect_handler)
    pusher.connect()
```

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde Stack Overflow o accediste directamente a Stack Overflow en español? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y sería útil saber el motivo, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara, explicitando que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Comment: Saludos! la verdad es que siempre lo he consultado en inglés, supongo porque son los resultados que aparecen de primero en Google y además siempre busco en inglés. Supongo llegué acá desde google y no me dí cuenta que era la versión en Español. Postearé acá y en inglés a ver que tal.

Comment: También supongo que estaba distraído y no vi que el formulario para postear la pregunta estaba en español. Si es algo muy recurrente, tal vez podrían agregar un mensaje de advertencia en la pregunta "Recuerda que la pregunta debes redactarla en Español"